# Selenium Parallel Testing - Running 2 methods from the same Class

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, testng

I have a java class that opens up two Chrome browsers, searches for "test 1" and "test 2", respectively. However, once both browsers open, only one browser with the google page will search for "test 1 test 2".

I believe this issue may be because I am calling the driver = new WebDriver from a parent class. However, I am not sure how to resolve the issue.

Here are my two methods that I am trying to run in parallel.

```
package webDrivertests;

public class googleTestClass extends Methods{

    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException {

        googleTestClass object1;
        object1 = new googleTestClass();
        object1.launchBrowser();
        object1.goToURL("https://www.google.com");
        object1.enterValue("name","q","google test 1");
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws InterruptedException {

        googleTestClass object2;
        object2 = new googleTestClass();
        object2.launchBrowser();
        object2.goToURL("https://www.google.com");
        object2.enterValue("name","q","google test 2");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

This is my xml file I use to call them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">
  <test thread-count="2" name="Test" parallel="methods">
    <classes>
      <class name="webDrivertests.googleTestClass"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

The parent method that includes the driver

```
package webDrivertests;

// import statements

public class Methods {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public void launchBrowser() {

         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public void goToURL(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
    }

        public void enterValue(String htmltype, String identifier, String value) throws InterruptedException {
        if (htmltype == "id") {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
            element.clear();
            element.sendKeys(value);
            element.submit();
        }
        if (htmltype =="name") {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(identifier));
            element.clear();
            element.sendKeys(value);
            element.submit();
        }

        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

}
```

Current Result: Two browsers are opened and each go to google.com. However only one browser will search for "test 1 test 2". Any help is appreciated! If possible, I would still like to use my parent class "Methods" as it contains a lot of methods I am using for my other real test cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what the class `googleTestClass` looks like ?

Comment: Updated! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What does the class `Methods` look like ? Please help furnish all information so that we can help you figure out your issue.

Comment: I have updated to include a shortened version of my entire Methods class. Removed some of the methods not being mentioned in googleTestClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your test code. WebDriver object is being declared as a static object.

So this causes every test method to share the same instance.

To fix the problem remove the `static` keyword from the WebDriver declaration in your `Methods` class and try again.

Comment: Hi again, is it possible to have another BeforeMethod that performs all of the common steps between the two test methods? For example I would like a BeforeMethod that sets up the Browser, goes to URL, etc. When I attempt to do this, I run into an NullPointer Error due to a new object being called in the before method. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I would request you to please open a new question with a detailed sample for your new query.

Comment: Hi Krishnan, I was able to get the question answered on another thread, thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Because of `static` declaration of the driver object in the class, it get's overridden parallel execution when second test called launchBrowser().

Obviously removing `static` will fix this issue but still you will fall in different issues of managing driver while your test bed and methods increase.

I would recommend to use any of [TestNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) that takes care of such requirement. We are using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) which is built upon TestNG and provides driver management, resource management and many more features which are crucial for web/mobile/webservices testing.